# Custom View make visible an hide

Tags: macos, cocoa, hide, custom-view

I am writing a cocoa app. I have a hidden custom View. I want to make it visible by clicking `show` and I want to hide it by clicking `hide`. My idea was to make it like in a window.
my code:

```
- (IBAction)show:(id)sender {
    [customView makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (IBAction)hide:(id)sender {
    [customView close];
}
```

It does not work for me. How can I do it?

Comment: Is customView an NSWindow or NSView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the show and close methods of an `NSWindow` - that is wrong.
Maybe you're looking for `NSView`'s `-setHidden:YES` and `-setHidden:NO` instead, which hides the NSView (inside its window).